# How can I set up the TinyMCE mention plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am trying to get the mention plugin to work with TinyMCE. The problem is: whenever I enable the plugin, I get the dreaded "tinymce is not defined" error. I think it may be loading the plugin "too soon", but I don't know how to delay the plugin load until TinyMCE is fully loaded.

Here's how I have the the init() configured:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    tinymce.init({
        selector:'textarea.update',
        menubar:false,
        toolbar:"undo redo | bold italic | bullist numlist | link unlink",
        width:'100%',
        plugins: "link,mention",
        mentions:
        {
            source: [
                { name: "Michael" },
                { name: "Erica" },
                { name: "Sloan" }
                ]
        }
    });
});
```

The Text area is

`<textarea class="update"></textarea>`

If I remove the mention option and the "mention" from the plugins list, it works fine. As soon as I put the plugin back into the "on" mode, it breaks.

How do I fix this?

Comment: mention? what is it.. A custom plugin?

Comment: It's a plugin I found on github. I am fairly sure the problem is how I am trying to use it, and not a plugin issue because there are a lot of people who are using it successfully. In other words, it's user error on my part, but I just don't know enough to know where. I can't find any example code...

Answer (score 0):

The problem (as [leakim571](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28335547/How-to-setup-the-TinyMCE-mention-plugin.html) so astutely pointed out) was that I was using [CacheFly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CacheFly) instead of hosting my own copy. When I got rid of the CacheFly reference, downloaded the whole TinyMCE package, and put the mention plugin in that package, everything started to work perfectly.